# Why my selection between two dates in the same table doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I use SQL server 2014, i try the following query to select between two dates in the same table, the datatype is `nvarchar`, i executed the following query it just shows me three rows such`('30/03/2015','30/04/2015','30/04/2015')`,but in reality there is`('29/02/2015','30/03/2015','31/04/2015','30/04/2015','30/04/2015')`

```
select RegisteredDate
from Student
where Student.RegisteredDate between convert(nvarchar, '30/01/2014', 103)
    and convert(nvarchar, '30/04/2015', 103)
```

Comment: How are the date formatted in you table?

Comment: This is why you should never store dates as nvarchar. You really don't need to allow for unicode characters here for sure. :S When you use the proper datatypes this type of problem fixes itself.

Comment: @MarkKram what do you mean? the RegisteredDate  datatype is nvarchar

Comment: You should really change that. This is slow and waste of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i have read the other answers and comments, i could recommend you to firstly change the datatype of "RegisteredDate" from "nvarchar" to "date". Secondly use this standard 'yyyy-MM-dd' below code is what you need

```
select RegisteredDate 
from Student
where Student.RegisteredDate between '2014-01-30' and '2015-04-30'
```

you will not be in need of any conversions, this is how i do it for myself

Answer (score 3):

Cast the other way round, other way you are comparing strings:

```
select RegisteredDate from Student
where convert(date, Student.RegisteredDate, 103) between '20140130' and '20150430'
```

The fact is that those dates saved as strings are ordered as:

```
'29/02/2015',
'30/03/2015',
'30/04/2015',
'30/04/2015',
'31/04/2015'
```

Now imagine where would you add filter values?

```
 '29/02/2015',

 '30/01/2014' --start date

/-------------\
|'30/03/2015',|
|'30/04/2015',|
|'30/04/2015',|
\-------------/

 '30/04/2015' --end date

 '31/04/2015'
```

So `between` will return you those three rows.
Also you have in your data `29/02/2015`. In `2015` February ends on `28`(you have incorrect data in tables already). You will never be able to insert such values if you choose types correctly.So the conclusion is:

**Use Appropriate data types for your data!**

Comment: it gives me this error
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Comparing Strings will use alphabetical order char by char starting from the left. For example:  20/01/1302  will be after 01/12/4016 as  the "2" char goes after the "1" char.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri but in the database its not organized this way(20150430) its organized(30/04/2015)

Comment: @R.salih, see edited answer. You should convert with appropriate format in order to eliminate convertion error

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri the datatype of the RegisterdDate is nvarchar

Comment: @R.salih, I understand. My select will select you the data you want. But for storing dates you should use Date type not nvarchar

Comment: If you still get a conversion error then you should check for rows that can't be converted. For instance if the registered date is 'zzzzzzzzz'. In a separate window run this `SET DATEFORMAT dmy

SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE ISDATE(Student.RegisteredDate) = 0` This will return rows where the date couldn't be converted. You'll have to manually fix these.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast your string to date instead of casting all the dates in the table to string.

You are casting all the records in the table to string and it might be millions of them. This way not only your performance will be better but more important you will compare them to dates, not as String.

```
SELECT RegisteredDate 
  FROM Student
 WHERE Student.RegisteredDate BETWEEN Convert(Date, '30/01/2014',103) AND Convert(Date, '30/04/2015', 103)
```

As I said in the comments, a string comparation uses alphabetical order one char after another starting from the left. For example: *20/01/1302* will be after *01/12/4016* as the "2" char goes after the "1" char in ASCII.

**Update**: convert Student.RegisteredDate to date if it is still in nvarchar type. I would recommend you to change the type if you can to this. It might be a source of bugs and performance problems if you do not do this.

SQL Server 2014 makes the string to dates conversion automagically but only if it needs to.  Comparing a '30/04/2015' string with a nvarchar is just a String comparation.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me what is ( to_Date)?

Comment: '30/01/2014' is just a String type like 'Helloworld' and 'FooBar'. They do not have any date meaning. 

Date types are optimized for database and make some checks so you wont find '31/02/2015' or '33/13'1233'. To_date will just change the type 
See for example: http://www.connectsql.com/2011/04/sql-server-basics-todate-function-in.html

Comment: @borjab, isnt it just for oracl?

Comment: to_date doesn't exist in SQL 2014.

Comment: `To_date is removed in SQL Server 2014 ` - it was never in sql server